# Selection.Find abruptly stopping

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a program which iterates through a collection of word documents and extracts the first table (will refactor code to more tables) within a subheader containing the words 'Report Layout.'

I have written code that largely works up until the value of my Selection.Range.Start exceeds 5 digits (97862 being the largest value). Now, this probably means my use of find is not correct, however I cannot figure out why it stops iterating through the document.

The problematic section:

```
            With wordApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.Find
                .ClearFormatting                                
                .Style = wrdDoc.Styles("Heading 3")     
                '.Text = strText       
                .Replacement.Text = ""                         
                .Forward = True                                 
                .Wrap = wdFindContinue                          
                .Format = True
                .MatchCase = False
                .MatchWholeWord = False
                .MatchWildcards = False
                .MatchSoundsLike = False
                .MatchAllWordForms = False
                .Execute
            If .Execute = False Then sh1.Cells(x, 3) = "not found"
            'If wordApp.Selection.Text = VBA.Trim$(astrHeadings(intItem)) Then


            End With

            iL4Count = iL4Count + 1                             
            ReDim Preserve Level2Heading(1 To iL4Count)         
            ReDim Preserve stringTable(1 To iL4Count)

            stringTable(iL4Count) = tableName
            Level2Heading(iL4Count) = wordApp.Selection.Range.Start
```

Full code:

```
Dim wrdDoc As Object, objFiles As Object, fso As Object, wordApp As Object
Dim sh1 As Worksheet
Dim x As Integer, Y As Integer, i As Integer, j As Integer, iL4Count As Integer, edTest As Integer, headerPos() As Integer, hPos As Integer
Dim rowCount As Long, columnCount As Long
Dim columnString As String
Dim validRange As String
Dim testRange As Object, testTable As Object
Dim astrHeadings As Variant
Dim Level2Heading() As Long
Dim tableHeader As String
Dim stringTable() As String
Dim regex As New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
Dim regmatch As MatchCollection

FolderName = "INSERT FOLDER PATH HERE"
regex.Pattern = "[a-zA-Z]"

Set sh1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set wordApp = CreateObject("Word.application")
Set objFiles = fso.GetFolder(FolderName).Files


x = 1
For Each wd In objFiles
    If InStr(wd, ".doc") And InStr(wd, "~") = 0 Then
        'Level2Heading.erase
        Erase Level2Heading, stringTable
        intItem = 0
        iCount = 0
        iL4Count = 0
        Set testRange = Nothing
        'testRange = Null

        sh1.Cells(x, 1) = wd.Name
        Set wrdDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(wd.Path, ReadOnly = True)

        astrHeadings = _
         wrdDoc.GetCrossReferenceItems(wdRefTypeHeading)


        For intItem = LBound(astrHeadings) To UBound(astrHeadings)
            ' Get the text and the level.
            strText = Trim$(astrHeadings(intItem))
            Set regmatch = regex.Execute(strText)
            edTest = regmatch.Item(0).FirstIndex
            strText = Right(strText, Len(strText) - edTest)
            intLevel = GetLevel(CStr(astrHeadings(intItem)))
            If intLevel = 2 Then
                tableName = strText
            End If

            'Debug.Print intLevel & " " & strText
            If intLevel = 3 Then
                wordApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=1, Count:=1 'wdCharacter, Count:=1

                With wordApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.Find
                    .ClearFormatting                                
                    .Style = wrdDoc.Styles("Heading 3")     
                    '.Text = strText       
                    .Replacement.Text = ""                          
                    .Forward = True                                 
                    .Wrap = wdFindContinue                          
                    .Format = True
                    .MatchCase = False
                    .MatchWholeWord = False
                    .MatchWildcards = False
                    .MatchSoundsLike = False
                    .MatchAllWordForms = False
                    .Execute
                If .Execute = False Then sh1.Cells(x, 3) = "not found"
                'If wordApp.Selection.Text = VBA.Trim$(astrHeadings(intItem)) Then


                End With

                iL4Count = iL4Count + 1                             
                ReDim Preserve Level2Heading(1 To iL4Count)         
                ReDim Preserve stringTable(1 To iL4Count)

                stringTable(iL4Count) = tableName
                Level2Heading(iL4Count) = wordApp.Selection.Range.Start      


                If InStr(UCase(strText), "REPORT LAYOUT") > 0 Then
                    hPos = hPos + 1
                    ReDim Preserve headerPos(1 To hPos)
                    headerPos(hPos) = iL4Count
                End If

                'End If
            End If

        Next intItem
        If iL4Count > 2 Then
            For iCount = LBound(headerPos) To UBound(headerPos) - 1
                x = x + 1
                itabCount = 0

                Set testRange = wrdDoc.Range(Level2Heading(headerPos(iCount) - 1), Level2Heading(headerPos(iCount)))
                Set testTable = testRange.Tables(1)
                rowCount = testTable.Rows.Count
                columnCount = testTable.Columns.Count
                For i = 1 To rowCount
                    Y = 3
                    For j = 1 To columnCount
                    On Error Resume Next
                        validRange = testTable.Cell(Row:=i, Column:=j).Range

                        If Err.Number = 0 Then
                            columnString = Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean(validRange)
                        Else
                            columnString = ""
                            Err.Clear
                        End If
                        If Y = 3 Then
                            sh1.Cells(x, 2) = stringTable(iCount + 1)
                        End If

                        sh1.Cells(x, Y) = columnString
                        ' sh1.Cells(x, Y) = aTable.Cell(Row:=i, Column:=j).Range.Text
                        Y = Y + 1
                    Next
                    x = x + 1
                Next
            Next iCount
        Else
            sh1.Cells(x, 2) = "Do Table Manually"
            x = x + 1
        End If

    wrdDoc.Close
    End If

Next wd
wordApp.Quit
End Sub
```

***EDIT*****
The issue appeared to be data related. The header went directly to a table and the find query did not know how to move past the record. Still wondering if this can be resolved with the move command.

Comment: As a follow up. It may be document related, although I have yet to find why it stops iterating. I partitioned my word document and while the formatting looks correct, it does not continue iterating.